# Using ETag to store cookie information in broswer

Tags: javascript, java, etag

IN my page we set some user specific unique hashed key for non logged in users. This helps us to track these users.

Issue is most cases user cleared browser history frequently and this information is removed.

I would like to store this key in more persisted  browser history like ETAG.
Could you please guide if ETAG can be used to store this kind of information in distributed system (Multiple apache running behind load balancer).

The key is UUID 32 char length.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wikipedia on using ETags https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Tracking_using_ETags

more in general, I'd rely on a plugin to solve this problem: http://samy.pl/evercookie/ as the solutions are diverse, complicated and continuously changing.

**IMPORTANT** beware there are ethical, and perhaps legal, concerns about tracking users that are intentionally trying to stay anonymous.

I'd recommend to just use cookies or localStorage, and let users decide over their privacy.

Comment: Thanks Benja this is helpful. I was also considering evercookie for same. Thanks for recommendations